# Why RecyclerView items disappear immediately when using Transition API?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

This is a question regarding the use of [Android Transition API](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50).

I am trying to animate the height change of a list, just like a dropdown menu.

I tried 2 approaches

1. Use a `RecyclerView` and animates its height change
2. Use a `ScrollView` > `LinearLayout` hierarchy and animates `ScrollView`'s height.

The 2nd approach works perfectly.
But the 1st approach has a serious glitch - when the collapse transition starts, items disappear immediately.

By looking at the below GIF you can observe clearly the difference:

[image]

*To be exact, items' visibility changes at the moment I change RecyclerView's LayoutParams, without waiting for the transition to finish, whatever it is expanding or collapsing*

#### Code

I have created a [minimal project on Github](https://github.com/siralam/RecyclerViewTransitionProblem).
If you just want to look at the code, here is the [MainActivity](https://github.com/siralam/RecyclerViewTransitionProblem/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/asksira/recyclerviewtransitionproblem/MainActivity.java).

#### Question

1. Is it possible to achieve `ScrollView`'s effect with a `RecyclerView`?
2. If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

My Idea is to do the transition of all the recycler view rows individual rather than the whole RecyclerView:

So when collapsing iterate through each ROW of a `RecyclerView` and do a transition. Remember to check for `null` if some rows are recycled they may return `null`. So after that collapse the whole recyclerView.

And like wise for the expanding do the same for the views.

This issue is cause by RecyclerView has many views with it but Scroll View has only one `View` nested in it.

Comment: Do you mean perform the transition on the viewholder?

Comment: Not a view holder in onClick just iterate using for loop for example `for(int i=item_count: item_count>=0: item_count--){ //get each item of the recyclerView and make a transition}`

Comment: Not a view holder in onClick just iterate using for loop for example `for(int i=item_count: item_count>=0: item_count--){ //get each item of the recyclerView and make a transition}`